# Batch Script to add white space at end of each line such that line size is 50 for each text file in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch script such that it goes to the specific directory and for each text file it adds space at the end of each line such that each line(col) size is 50. It should be updating the same file instead of creating a new file.

Example: I have `5` files, `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, `file4` and `file5`. Each file has multiple lines like `file1` has `3` lines in it:

```
lin 1 (length of line 27)
line 2 (length of line 37)
line 3 (length of line 47)
```

At the end output of the `file1` should be:

```
lin 1 (length of line 50)
line 2 (length of line 50)
line 3 (length of line 50)
```

By adding space at the end of the line. Same should be repeated for all files for each line.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO lets start
REM set current path 
set pathname="C:\Users\Desktop\New folder"
REM Change the Directory
cd /d %Pathname%
echo Directory changed to %Pathname%
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
echo %%x
for /f " tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%%x) do (
    echo %%a        
 )
)

PAUSE
```

Comment: Store the line with 50 spaces appended in a variable and use substring to output only the first 50 places (if the line was longer this will cut off the overhang). This is much easier in PowerShell with the `.PadRight(50,' ')` method.

Comment: I am new to PowerShell, can you share me the code if you don't mind

Comment: Powershell with aliases, one line: `foreach ($File in gci X:\path\*.txt){(gc $File)|%{$_.PadRight(50,' ')}|set-Content $File}`

Comment: `for %%F in ("%pathname%\*.txt") do for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%%~I") do set "LINE=%%L" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & if "!LINE:~,50!"=="!LINE!" (set "LINE=!LINE!                                                  " & echo/!LINE:~,50!) else (echo/!LINE!) & endlocal` (this just echoes the new text to the console; note that the command `set "LINE=!LINE!                                                  "` contains 50 spaces; to truncate lines longer than 50 char.s rather than keeping it, replace the whole `if`/`else` block by just the parenthesised stuff between `if` & `else`)

Comment: @LotPings, thanks, what worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch script that does what you desire (check out the `rem` remarks in the code):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "PATHNAME=C:\Users\Desktop\New folder" & rem // (root directory)
set "SPACES=                                                  " & rem // (50 spaces)
set "TRUNC=#" & rem // (set empty to not truncate lines longer than 50 char.s)

rem // Enumerate matching files:
for %%F in ("%PATHNAME%\*.txt") do (
    rem // Write to temporary file:
    > "%%~F.tmp" (
        rem // Read a file line by line (empty lines are skipped):
        for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%%~F") do (
            rem // Store current line:
            set "LINE=%%L"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Check whether line is not longer than 50 char.s:
            if "!LINE:~,50!"=="!LINE!" (
                rem // Not longer, so pad with spaces, then truncate:
                set "LINE=!LINE!%SPACES%"
                echo(!LINE:~,50!
            ) else (
                rem // Longer, so check whether to truncate or keep:
                if defined TRUNC (
                    echo(!LINE:~,50!
                ) else (
                    echo(!LINE!
                )
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
    rem // Replace original file by temporary one:
    > nul move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

You should backup your files before checking, because your input text files become replaced.